# to retrieve data from database and show it with tha radio buttons with radio botton containing the data value instruts 1.2

Tags: java, html, jsp, radio-button, struts-1

In struts 1.2, how can i highlight radio button according to my database value?I am using Form bean to set other text field values.

```
<tr>
    <td align = "right" nowrap>SEX:</td>
    <td align= "right" nowrap> <html:radio property="sex" value="male"/>MALE
    <html:radio property="sex" value="female"/>FEMALE</td>
</tr>
```

I am using form bean an following java code:`stuform.setSex((String)tempmap.get("SEX"));`
here stuform is object of StudentForm class and tempmap contain data from select query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an if statement, I am using jstl if statement but you can use  tag too.

```
<c:if test="${myForm.sex=='female'}">
    <html:radio property="sex" value="female"/><span style="color: red;">FEMALE</span></td>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thnx for the help Susie..but what is myForm ?is it a BEAN Object or html:Form name?

Comment: It's a bean object. You form should be backed by a java bean object which has "sex" property in it.

Comment: I have tried above code but now it is displaying single radio button based on the value of sex in form.But my requirement is to display the both male and female and get checked only one.